# Help writing to two files simultaneously in PHP?

Tags: php

In the script below, I try to write in the same time in two files, but don't perform. How I can do it ?

```
$filename1 = "guestbook.doc" ;
$filename2 = "cour.doc" ;

$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);

$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);

$message = stripslashes(nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['message'])));

$d = date ( "d/m/Y H:i:s" )

$handle1 = fopen($filename1, "w+");
$handle2 = fopen($filename2, "a+");

if ($handle1 && $handle2) {
    fwrite($handle1, "<b>$name</b> "." - $d<br>$message<br><hr>\n");
    fwrite($handle2, "<b>$name</b> ".$email." - $d<br>$message<br>\n");
}
if ($handle1) {
    fclose($handle1);
}
if ($handle2) {
    fclose($handle2);
}

then
{
header('Location: contact.php?' . http_build_query($_POST));
}
?>
```

Comment: "don't perform" is very vague. what doesn't work? one of the writes? both? what errors do you have? what contents do you get in the files that you weren't expecting?

Answer (score 2):

One thing I do notice is that is kinda odd is :

```
then
{
header('Location: contact.php?' . http_build_query($_POST));
}
```

`then` is not a valid control structure.  It's `if`/`elseif`/`else`.

Answer (score 0):

writing to a file in PHP is procedural it will wait for handle1 to be written before moving onto handle2. It will not write them at the same time. There must be an error occurring or its not getting inside the if statement `if($handle1 && $handle2)` . It possibly cannot open those files for writing due to permission problems? are there any errors at all?

Try replacing that if statement with something like this and see if it breaks?

```
if (is_writable($filename1) or die ("Can not write to ".$filename1)) {
  fwrite($handle1, "<b>$name</b> "." - $d<br>$message<br><hr>\n");
}
if (is_writable($filename2) or die ("Can not write to ".$filename2)) {
  fwrite($handle2, "<b>$name</b> "." - $d<br>$message<br><hr>\n");
}
```

Comment: Sorry but -1: `is_writable` — Tells whether the *filename* is writable.

Comment: @Alix, good point, I've updated the sample but it should really then be restructured to just match one of the examples from http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: nothing wrong with doing an is_writable test, but you need to do it BEFORE you open the file handle. No point in checking if there's a barn door to close after you've already tried closing it.

Answer (score 0):

Just write one under another it will work perfect.

```
<?php

$filename = "guestbook.doc" ;
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$message = stripslashes(nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['message'])));
$d = date ( "d/m/Y H:i:s" )
$handle1 = fopen($filename, "w+");
$size = filesize($filename);
fwrite($handle, "<b>$name</b> "." - $d<br>$message<br><hr>\n");
$text = fread($handle, $size);
fclose($handle);

$filename = "cour.doc" ;
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$message = stripslashes(nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['message'])));
$d = date ( "d/m/Y H:i:s" )
$handle = fopen($filename1, "w+");
$size = filesize($filename1);
fwrite($handle, "<b>$name</b> ".$email." - $d<br>$message<br>\n");
$text = fread($handle, $size);
fclose($handle);

?>
```